# Is there a way to list library dependencies in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, boost, msbuild, linker, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to build a C++ project with Boost and Cinder on Windows Server 2008 with MSBuild without success.  I've build the same project on my Windows 7 machine under VS2013 and MSBuild, however on the server it is saying that it can't open a library by the name of "threadsafestatics.lib"

I've never heard of threadsafestatics.lib and my Google-foo hasn't brought me any luck finding anything about it online.

Is there a way to find out what part of my project is depending on this library?

Comment: I'm not so sure, but I think it is being used by the Boost library, so since you used Boost, probably it is the one throwing that dependency issue

Comment: Get ILSpy and you may have to fish for your third party that dependencies ... and those 3rd party dependencies may use the library of which you speak..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threadsafestatics.lib` is a new library from the November 2013 CTP. If you are compiling with the CTP, you must add its installed `lib` folder to `Project` > `Properties` > `VC++ Directories` > `Library Directories`.

If you installed the CTP to its default location on a 64-bit machine, the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP\lib`

You can also use the macros `$(VC_CTP_Nov2013_LibraryPath_x86)`, `$(VC_CTP_Nov2013_LibraryPath_x64)`, or `$(VC_CTP_Nov2013_LibraryPath_ARM)` depending on your target architecture.

Comment: While it might be a few weeks too late, thanks anyways!  Hopefully anyone else searching around online will find your answer useful.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is: "Is there a way to find out what part of my project is depending on this library?"

Answer (score 5):

Providing debug level output for the build process helped to work around the problem:

```
Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity
```

Comment: this needs more upvotes. really helped me without installing any other tools. This should be your first start!

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed "CompilerCTP.Nov2013"Patch package, and using toolset of ctp2013,you can try to change toolset into 2013 with the following steps:

project -> property ->config property -> platform toolset ->Visual Studio 2013 (v120).